# After updating to Ventura 13.6.5, the login items are missing and the computer is extremely slow

Tags: performance, software-update, bug, ventura

I use MacBook Air (M1, 16GB, 2020). Today I updated the macbook to macOS Ventura 13.6.5.

After the update,

- The computer boots up and I can login to it.
- The CPU usage is 1% (i.e. 99% idle) and the RAM usage is 5GB (i.e. 11GB available). The disk I/O, the network, etc. are all idle as well as far as I check them via `Activity Monitor.app`. The SSD has more than 50GB empty space.
- However, *all* of the login items are missing (I checked `System Preferences.app` but the list was made empty for unknown reason).
- And every single action takes extremely long time. For example, clicking the apple logo at the top-left of the screen takes 1 minute just to show the popup menu. I can literally do nothing. Firefox doesn't open even 5 minutes after I click its icon.

What I tried:

- Safe Boot: Nothing changed.
- Reinstall OS: Nothing changed.

What can I do now?

---

I'm searching "Ventura 13.6.5" for Twitter (X) and it seems many users have the same problem:

- > I updated to ventura 13.6.5 and slack and vpn are gone. ([link](https://twitter.com/sombriks/status/1768716828769992807))
- > After updating to ventura 13.6.5, many applications now don't work. ([link](https://twitter.com/kmori644/status/1768653253364064600))
- > After updating to Ventura 13.6.5, all of the login items are missing now and Slack doesn't start. ([link](https://twitter.com/capytan_el34/status/1768168049138606196))
- > Many coworkers report me their computers became so slow after updating to Ventura 13.6.5... ([link](https://twitter.com/oratosuk/status/1767422478564139089))

Apple community:

- > Startup files missing after Ventura 13.6.5 upgrade ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255526308?sortBy=best))
- > Apple Mail Folders Missing After Updating to MacOS Ventura 13.6.5 ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255524066?sortBy=best))
- > Some apps won't launch and login items disappeared Post Ventura update on MacBook Pro ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255520159?answerId=260266468022&sortBy=best#260266468022))

Comment: Can you downgrade to Big Sur and see if that has any effect?  If not, I fear you may be looking at a hardware issue where the logic board needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

I found a related thread in Apple community: [*Some apps won't launch and login items disappeared Post Ventura update on MacBook Pro*](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255520159)

> This issue occurred after updating to macOS Venture 13.6.5.
>
> Some apps (1password, Teams for Mac, XQuartz, Ivanti Secure Access Client, etc.) no longer launch, all login items are not displayed, and new login items cannot be registered.

According the thread

- Many users have the same problem as mine.
- They report safe boot and reinstalling Ventura doesn't work.
- They report upgrading to Sonoma resolves the problem.

So I upgraded to Sonoma. Now there is no problem and the missing login items are back.

Just installing a minor update of Ventura made me waste 5 hours for debugging and forced me to upgrading to Sonoma, which I wanted to avoid for compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to 13.6.5, I was seeing several apps like Slack, Teams, 1password, and Palo Alto VPN that were configured as login items hang on start (even when launched manually). Like yours, the login items settings were blank, but the system was not notably slow for the apps that worked.

Checking the logs in the Console app, I noticed that backgroundtaskmanagementd was repeatedly crashing while trying to upgrade its database:

```
backgroundtaskmanagementd   performUpgradesAndMigrations entered
backgroundtaskmanagementd   found v8 store at /var/db/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagement/BackgroundItems-v8.btm
backgroundtaskmanagementd   Upgrading store from version 8 to 9: /var/db/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagement/BackgroundItems-v8.btm
backgroundtaskmanagementd   code signing internal problem: unexpected error 
backgroundtaskmanagementd   MacOS error: -67048
backgroundtaskmanagementd   Error registering stapled ticket: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67048 "(null)"
backgroundtaskmanagementd   System Keychain Always Supported set via feature flag to disabled
backgroundtaskmanagementd   TrustSettingsUseXPC is enabled (via feature flags)
backgroundtaskmanagementd   Received configuration update from daemon (initial)
ReportCrash Formulating fatal 309 report for corpse[1076] backgroundtaskmanagementd
```

So I renamed it to start fresh:

```
sudo mv /var/db/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagement/BackgroundItems-v8.btm{,.bak}
```

Several seconds later, backgroundtaskmanagementd restarted again, created a v9 file, and apps began working correctly.